# Rails model with column that can represent multiple datatypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, types

I'm curious if it's ok to create a column in a rails postgresql database with type = text but then when calling that column, convert whatever is stored inside it into various other types of data (ex. date, integer, etc.)

For context, I’m creating a tool that allows a set of questions to be created and many users can answer the questions. The questions can expect a response of `paragraph`, `number` or `date`. Responses will be stored in the `question_responses` table. Rather than creating 3 columns for the various response types (`paragraph`, `number`, & `date`), I would prefer to create a single text column named `response`. And then, convert whatever is stored in `response` to either `text`, `integer` or `date` (as needed). Thoughts?

Here are my models:

```
# app/models/survey.rb
class Survey
  has_many :questions
end

# app/models/question.rb
class Questions
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :responses
  enum response_type: { 'Paragraph': 0, 'Number': 1, 'Date': 2 }
end

# app/models/question_response.rb
# has column in db named "response" with type: text
class QuestionResponse
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question

  def converted_response
    case question.response_type
    when 'Paragraph'
      response
    when 'Number'
      response.to_i
    when 'Date'
      response.to_date
    end
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User
  has_many :responses
end
```

Comment: Of course you can do so -- just need to be careful to persist the data in a consistent matter and handle failed conversions gracefully.  A begin...rescue block in converted_response would be a good start and testing coverage a better finish.

Comment: You could also just use Rails built in [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) method to store the types as YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done. Thanks to @dbugger, it is important to also remember to validate data stored in `response` as well as use begin rescue blocks to protect against instances where the `response` cannot be converted.